# How to show the order equality of modified Bessel function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, bessel-functions

The modified Bessel function of order n of the first kind is given by

$$I_n(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac{1}{2}x)^{2m+n}}{m!\Gamma(m+n+1)}$$

where $\Gamma$ is defined by an improper integral,

$$\Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$

How can I show the following equality of order

$$I_n(x)\sim \frac{(\frac{1}{2}x)^n}{n!}$$

where $n\geqslant0$.

Comment: As $x \to 0$? It's just the first term of the series.

Comment: This follows immediately from the power series. Divide both sides by $(x/2)^n/n!$ and take the limit $x \to 0$.